# WSO2 API Manager - How to make wso2 support PATCH method

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to create a API in wos2am and its httpmethod is PATCH.
How can I let wso2am to support PATCH? or do I need to add some custom features?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the API Manager does not support the Patch method. There is a plan to support it in future, but I cannot tell a release timeline. It should be first supported by the underlying Synapse.

Answer (score 0):

APIM manager uses synapse as is underlying mediation engine which currently supports OPTIONS,GET, POST, PUT, DELETE..